# How do I use CSS to give a section a background that doesn't scroll with the page?

Tags: html, css, background-image, parallax

I can't figure out what is being used to achieve the parallax effect here: [www.alwayscreative.net](http://www.alwayscreative.net) (the bottom part, "We are inspired..." ect.)

I'm trying to do something similar on [my own portfolio site](http://pftest.fhero.net). Here's the CSS in question (which closely mirrors their own as of the moment):

```
.plx-bg1 {
background: transparent url(../img/plx-bg.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;
color: #fff;
max-height: 980px;
padding: 25% 0;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 100%;
margin-top: 50px;}

.multiplebgs .plx-bg1 {
background-image: url(../img/plx-seperator.png), url(../img/plx-seperator-bottom.png), url(../img/plx-bg.jpg);
background-position: 0 0, 0 bottom, center bottom;
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat-x, no-repeat;
background-size: auto auto, auto auto, cover!important;}
```

I seem to be able to get a parallax effect by adding 'fixed' to the plx-bg1 background class (or with different CSS) but I cannot get it to work in conjunction with the multiplebgs class and the borders on top and bottom as they have done (which is really cool) as adding a 'fixed' property breaks it, and that is obviously not how they have done it....

Looking through the code on their site I can't for the life of me figure out where or what exactly they're using to make the actual parallax effect work?

Comment: By "parallax effect," do you mean the background of the section not scrolling with the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that they also have this in their CSS, which you've left out:

```
.inspiration {
    background-attachment: scroll,scroll,fixed;
}
```

Perhaps you missed it because it's held within a media query.

Comment: Ah, looks like I did indeed miss that  - great, it's working now (updated if you wanna see :D). Thanks for pointing that out, as well as the quick response! I did try looking through the media queries for something relevant but missed that one somehow.

edit: okay, *now* it's updated.

Comment: Cool, glad it was that simple. It's nice what you can do just with CSS. I hadn't seen it done with multiple background before, so nice to see this example.